# How to send JS object in query parameter with dynamic values in a GET/POST request

Tags: javascript

What to do when one needs to send dynamic query parameters as an object to a GET or POST request?

For example, in `http://example.com/shine?n=1&i=0`, **n** and **i** are query parameters and they are supposed to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the framework allows to send a separate object (which will be converted to query parameters in the background), then one can create JavaScript object with regex values:

```
var obj = { 
            n: /.*/, 
            i: /.*/
          }
```

Nockjs allows you to do it like this:

```
.post('http://example.com/shine')
.query({ 
        n: /.*/, 
        i: /.*/
        });
```

Or you can use regex on the url directly like this:

```
.post(/http://example.com/shine?n=.*&i=.*/)
```